# using filter/contains in jquery

Tags: jquery, contains

wonder if anyone can help out;

I'm trying to get my head around using filter in jquery.

Basically I'm trying to figure out some code that pretty much does what it needs to do.

```
if ($(".regionSubHeader span:contains('19-07-2014')").length > 0){

if($('.regionFilterLnk span:contains("Nights - 2")').length > 0 || $('.regionFilterLnk span:contains("Nights - 3")').length > 0 || $('.regionFilterLnk span:contains("Nights - 4")').length > 0 || $('.regionFilterLnk span:contains("Nights - 5")').length > 0){
$( '#thirtydaysmessage' ).show();
}
else{
$( '#thirtydaysmessage' ).hide();
}
```

problem is if Nights - 21 is in the span it registers it as positive in the logic - I'm guessing this is because it's using contains.

I have been reading about this and the soloution seems to be to use filter, but I can't get my head around how to carry out a bunch of statements that way, eg something like this;

```
$(".regionSubHeader span").filter(function() {
return $(this).text() === "Start date - 19-07-2014";
 }).css("font-size", "60px");
```

but instead of the .css I would need to do further checks as above (the number of nights checks), perhaps a function?

any pointers on how I can carry out a bunch of statements with the filter outcome ?

Thanks

Comment: You can chain methods in jQuery.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a generic function that takes selectors and match patterns as arguments and returns possible matches:

```
var getElemsContaining = function ( elem, pattern ) {
    var matches = [];
    $( elem ).each(function ( i, el ) {
        var re = new RegExp( pattern, 'ig' );
        if ( el.text().match( re )) {
            links.push( el );
        }
    });
    return links;
}

if( getElemsContaining( '.regionSubHeader span', '19-07-2014' ) && getElemsContaining( '.regionFilterLnk span', 'Nights - 2|Nights - 3|Nights - 4' ) ){
    // Do lots of stuff here
}
```

Comment: great thanks, I've adapted this and learnt quite a bit today about regex & matching !